# Linked list : Method to verify if the list contains an element?

Tags: java, list

I am writing a method that is suposed to return TRUE if the element in the linked list or FALSE if it's not in the list.

I was wondering if there was a much more neater way to code this ...

Here's a quick view of my code :

```
public boolean estElement(T item) {
    boolean elmExist = false;
    this.actual = this.head;

    if (item != null && this.actual != null) {
        T elmSearch;

        while (this.actual != null && !elmExist) {
            elmSearch = actual.getElement();
            if (elmSearch.equals(item)) {
                elmExist = true;
            } else {
                this.actual = this.actual.nextLink();
            }
        }           
    }

    return elmExist;
}
```

Comment: Break the loop as soon as you find the element exists - may simplify your code a bit...

Comment: I think you want your variable name `actual` to have the semantic of `current` (actual does not mean anything in this context). Moreover I don't see why you would this to be an attribute instead of a simple local variable

Answer (score 1):

Exist the loop and the function as soon as the element is found :

```
while (this.actual != null && !elmExist)
{
    elmSearch = actual.getElement();
    if (elmSearch.equals(item)) return true;
    this.actual = this.actual.nextLink(); 
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do shorter, like in the following snippet (I find this prettier than a loop with a break or a return) :

```
public boolean estElement(T item) {    
    Node<T> current;
    for (current = head ; current != null && current.value != item ; current = current.nextLink()); 
    return current != null;
}
```

Just as a remark,

```
if (myVar != null) { while (myVar != null) { ... } }
```

is just equivalent to

```
while (myVar != null) { ... }
```

so you don't need to write the same condition twice. However, if you had `else/else if` clauses or additional instuctions in the `if` block then it would no longer be equivalent.